# Using PHP to find specific entry in JSON URL response

Tags: php, mysql, json, steam

I am trying to find out whether a user is part of a Steam group. To do this, I'm using Steam's Web API, and using URL:

```
https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetUserGroupList/v1/?key=APIKEYHERE&steamid=STEAMID64HERE
```

To get a JSON response of all groups that a user is part of.
Now I want to find out if they're part of my specific group with ID: 1111111 using PHP.

How would one do that? Currently I have the code being decoded like so:

```
$groupid = "1111111";
$url = "https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetUserGroupList/v1/?key=APIKEYHERE&steamid=STEAMID64HERE";
$result = file_get_contents($url);
// Will dump a beauty json :)
$pretty = json_decode($result, true);
```

This makes the $pretty variable contain the entire JSON response.
How would I use PHP to find the group ID in a response that looked like this?

```
    {
    "response": {
        "success": true,
        "groups": [
            {
                "gid": "4458711"
            },
            {
                "gid": "9538146"
            },
            {
                "gid": "11683421"
            },
            {
                "gid": "24781197"
            },
            {
                "gid": "25160263"
            },
            {
                "gid": "26301716"
            },
            {
                "gid": "29202157"
            },
            {
                "gid": "1111111"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

Can't figure it out.
Any help? :)

Comment: please check my answer and let me any other help

Comment: Didn't work, see comment

Comment: checking.. plz wait

Comment: I have edit my answer please check one more time. and let me know any other help..

Comment: Have replied to your solution, doesn't work - throws an error.

Comment: http://codepad.org/urgdyKqi it's works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to check whether user is exist in the response or not

```
$groupid = "1111111";
$is_exists = false;
$url = "https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetUserGroupList/v1/?key=APIKEYHERE&steamid=STEAMID64HERE";
$result = file_get_contents($url);

// Will dump a beauty json :)
$pretty = json_decode($result, true);
foreach ($pretty['response']['groups'] as $key => $value) {
    if($value['gid'] == $groupid) {
        $is_exists = true;
        break;
    }
}

// check is_exists
```

Check that above variable `$is_exists` for true or false

Answer (score 1):

```
        $groupid = "1111111";
    $url = "https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetUserGroupList  /v1/?key=APIKEYHERE&steamid=STEAMID64HERE";
    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    // Will dump a beauty json :)
    $pretty = json_decode($result);
    $s = $pretty->response->groups;
    foreach($s as $value)
    {
        if((int) $groupid  ==  $value->gid)
        {
            echo  "Found";
        }else
        {
            echo  "Not found";  
        }   

    }
```

Comment: It keeps returning Not found, although the groupid is actually in the response.

Comment: @peter : I have edit my answer please check one more time. and let me know any other help

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/test.php on line 8

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/test.php on line 8

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/test.php on line 9